# Why xargs is used with echo, but not sort?

Tags: xargs

At xargs man page there is a usage example

```
cut -d: -f1 < /etc/passwd | sort | xargs echo
```

Why in this case echo is used with xargs, and sort without,

even both command has similar syntax where arguments follows command?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Try what? It's a teorethical question about man page example.

Comment: Is it? both do different things. Therefore is not about the way the man page authors decided to do it. (try it: if you try it, then you will know why I asked you to try it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` connects the output of the left side with the input of the right side.

`echo` prints its arguments. It doesn't do anything with the data sent to its input. Therefore, `xargs` is used to call `echo` with the input.

`sort`, on the other hand, doesn't sort its arguments, but its input data.

Therefore, it makes sense to directly put input into sort.

(However, `xargs echo` really makes no sense. That really only converts the output of `sort` to arguments, just to convert these back to output. It's not quite sure what the intention here: `cut -d: -f1 < /etc/passwd | sort` would have worked just the same; ok, it would have a newline after every user, but in all honesty, this isn't a job for xargs, but for `sed` or `awk`, which would have directly done what the user would've wanted in the first place, on /etc/passwd; however, I'm pretty sure you're not very interested in the sensibility of that command line, more in why xargs is used that way.)

Comment: The `xargs echo` will end up putting the sorted values all on a single line

Comment: yes, I know; that's why I wrote that without, there would be a newline after every user name.

Comment: That difference is precisely why `xargs` is being used, though

Comment: well, yes, but it's really not a very good example of what you'd use xargs for (putting a couple thousand arguments to echo can indeed become problematic, and a single line of `sed` could've done the same). Anyways, I feel that's really not OP's focus, at all.

Comment: And `xargs` will do that without `echo`’s help — `sort | xargs` is sufficient here. (Or `sort | tr '\n' ' '`.)

Comment: Yeah, I wonder why they couldn't find a better example for their `man` page; the `tr` solution is better, by the way, as it doesn't rely on spawning a process with potentially overly many or large arguments that haven't even been sanitized. (not that it really matters. It's just a bad example. You can build more useful examples.)